# How can I make this function shorter with ES6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This function is a small part of the logic I need to implement, the code is getting super long, I am looking for creative ways to write this tasks in short format.

```
if (type === '30d') {
  self.setState({
      startDate: last30d,
      endDate: now
    },
    () => {
      this.fetchPeriod('income');
      this.fetchPeriod('expense');
      this.fetchSettings();
    }
  );
} else if (type === '15d') {
  self.setState({
      startDate: last15d,
      endDate: now
    },
    () => {
      this.fetchPeriod('income');
      this.fetchPeriod('expense');
      this.fetchSettings();
    }
  );
} else if (type === '7d') {
  self.setState({
      startDate: last7d,
      endDate: now
    },
    () => {
      this.fetchPeriod('income');
      this.fetchPeriod('expense');
      this.fetchSettings();
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to make an object which relates each `type` to the `startDate`, then pass it to `setState`:

```
const startDatesByType = {
  '30d': last30d,
  '15d': last15d,
  '7d': last7d,
};
const startDate = startDatesByType[type];
if (startDate) {
  self.setState({ startDate, endDate: now },
    () => {
      this.fetchPeriod('income');
      this.fetchPeriod('expense');
      this.fetchSettings();
    }
  );
}
```

If possible, you might consider changing the `last30d` and related variables so that they're *only* in the `startDatesByType` object, rather than being multiple standalone variables.

Answer (score 1):

get the start date and set state once instead of setting it in multiple conditions.

```
const startDate = type === '30d' ? last30d : ( type === '15d' ? last15d : last7d);

if ('30d 15d 7d'.includes(type)) {

  self.setState({ startDate: startDate, endDate: now },
    () => {
      this.fetchPeriod('income');
      this.fetchPeriod('expense');
      this.fetchSettings();
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: short and sweet

Comment: OP's original logic only calls `setState` if `type` is `7d`, `15d`, or `30d` (see how he has `else if`s, but not `else`s) - this code assumes that, if the `type` is not `30d` or `15d`, it will be `7d`, which may not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Create a map of `type => startDate` and use that for the setState call.

Answer (score 0):

Your "bottle-neck" is `startDate`, consider making a generic `getLastNDates`:

```js
self.setState({ startDate: getLastNDates(n) , endDate: getLastNDates(0) },
      () => {
        this.fetchPeriod('income');
        this.fetchPeriod('expense');
        this.fetchSettings();
      }
    );
```